# apply shade to flutter color variable

Tags: flutter, dart, colors

I have defined a variable that holds a color value and when I setstate the screen, I always change this color. I want to use this color both as normal and shade100 in my application. However, my code is giving an error below.

```
late Color objeColor;
objeColor = Colors.orange;

Container(
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
   shape: BoxShape.circle,
   color: objeColor, // there is no error *******
   ),),


Container(
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
   shape: BoxShape.circle,
   color: objeColor.shade100, // there is error *******
),),
```

error

> The getter 'shade100' isn't defined for the type 'Color'.
> Try importing the library that defines 'shade100', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'shade100'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shade100` is a getter for [`MaterialColor`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialColor-class.html). You can do

```dart
 late MaterialColor objeColor;
 ...
 color: objeColor.shade100
```

Comment: Thanks, this completely solved my problem.

Comment: Glad to help, you can explore more from attached link.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the shade of the color again in the widget tree. Though you've got plenty of other methods to manipulate the color with. For example, `objeColor.withAlpha(75)` looks exactly like `Colors.orange.shade100` so it would perfectly fit your needs. In other usecases you can try to experiment with other methods, like `withOpacity()`.